# "Get a 3-Legged Token with Authorization Code Grant" generates an Error 400

Tags: oauth-2.0, autodesk-forge

I am trying to create a webpage that implements Step 1 of the "[Get a 3-Legged Token with Authorization Code Grant](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/)" process described in Autodesk's Forge tutorial. But when I run it I get an error: Error : 400 - Invalid redirect_uri

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html lang="en"> 
    <head>
    <title>Get_a_3-Legged_Token_with_Authorization_Code_Grant.php</title>
    </head> 
    <body> 
    <?php 
    // Derivedfrom API tutorial here: 
    // https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/

    $client_id                          = "HAqDtKO7VbuRgH0nL0MFJ0B02ElBEK3l";
    $forge_Callback_URL_w_query_string  = "http%3A%2F%2prod.sonautics.com/send_scan.php%3Fcmd%3Drefresh";
    $forge_Your_WebSite_URL             = "httpp%3A%2F%2prod.sonautics.com";

    echo    '<a href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authorize?response_type=code'
        .   '&client_id=' . $client_id      
        .   '&redirect_uri=' . forge_Callback_URL_w_query_string    
        .   '&scope=data:read">Click here to grant access to your data!</a>'; ?> 
    </body> 
    </html>
```

I am receiving a page that says:

> Oops
>
> Error : 400 - Invalid redirect_uri
>
> We're experiencing problems with the application configuration.
>
> Connecting Application
>
> Please try again later.

My code above is very simple:can you help me identify the source of the error and tell me how to fix it?

Comment: I see your example was using `httpp` instead of `http`, maybe that affected too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `redirect_uri` parameter should be matched with the `Callback URL` like the following snapshot in your Forge app of this `client id` you mentioned here. Please check if they are mismatched currently.

Besides,

the oath scope for viewing models via Forge Viewer is recommended to use `viewables:read` instead. The scope `data:read` can be used to read your model files in your bucket by others once your token with this scope is exposed. Please check this announcement: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/new-viewablesread-scope

[image]

Comment: It turns out that even though the example shows the unencoded version of the URI,  it did not like it.  But I just changed the URI to "https://" and it worked.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I am following the 3-legged tutorial, and I matched the URI and URL, tried swapping the data:read for viewables:read, and tried switching to `https://` and not `http://` but I'm still getting an error `Not Found. The requested URL /parking/oauth/callback was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`
Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: I am having the similar issue. I want to know for how long the authorization code is valid?

Comment: @Sumana I believe it's valid for 7 days, this can be found on the [authentication docs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/overview/).

Comment: @Sumana the lifetime of the Autodesk Forge OAuth authorization code is 1 minute.