# Autodesk Forge API tutorial Get a 3-Legged Token 404 error

Tags: request, autodesk-forge

I have a similar issue to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489324/get-a-3-legged-token-with-authorization-code-grant-generates-an-error-400/51490341#comment93043717_51490341).

I am following the 3-legged tutorial on the Forge API website [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/), and I matched the callback URI and URL, tried swapping the `data:read` for `viewables:read`, and tried switching to `https://` and not `http://` but I'm still getting an error when I run the app and login via the link in the tutorial which I adjusted with my information.

The error I get is:

```
Not Found. 
The requested URL /parking/oauth/callback was not found on this server. 
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: This appears to be that your local server is not correctly implemented or the callback urls do not match. Which sample are you following? You will need to make sure the callback urls of your sample and that of Forge app match.

Comment: I updated the question with a link to the tutorial itself. But I've already mentioned that I made sure the URI and URL do match...

Comment: My code is `redirect_uri=http://www.mycallback.com/oauth/callback` and on the website in my app it's `http://www.mycallback.com/oauth/callback`

Comment: Is your server redirecting the path www.mycallback.com/oauth/callback to anywhere? Check your code that handles the callback, add a breakpoint to see if the handler was called after the oauth redirects. Better do a search in your code for 'parking' which was added to the path that the error was called out.

Comment: My code is:

`app.get('/',function(req,res){
 res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../samples/3_legged.html'));
 console.log("Response Sent :)");
});`

I can see in the cmd window that the `Response sent :)` appears.
There is no "parking" anywhere in any of my code..

Comment: Have you got other middleware in your app? Coz if the code above is the only handler there is your app should send the html file regardless of the request path, with or w/o 'parking'. And since per console output your server received the callback you should narrow the issue down to your Node app.

Comment: Hi Bryan. I'm not sure I know enough to understand your answer. I don't have any other "middleware".. just those lines of code. What could be the issue with my Node app and how can I debug it..?

Comment: You can add breakpoints in your handler to monitor if your code is really stepped into and not any other when oauth redirects back. When it hits your breakpoint you will also want to look into this request redirected to your handler and check if the referrer is correct (should be our endpoints) and the authorization code is present. Visual Code/Webstorm are good choices to debug Node. If you only had one handler at root your callback path won’t work anyway coz it is not handled. Look around and read up on some tutorials to skill up on Node.